# Sproutcore and JSON Data

Tags: json, sproutcore

How can i read JSON data in Sproutcore?

Answer (score 7):

`SC.json.decode(json)` will decode and `SC.json.encode(json)` will encode. Where possible this will use the browser's native implementation which should be quite fast. Alternatively it will fall back on a JS based parser.